# checking whether a string exists in a list

Tags: python, string, list, memory

I am simply trying to figure out why the simple code below does not return anything back even though Im almost positive i am correct:

```
mike = [1,2,3,3,"error"]

if "error" in mike == True:
    print(True)
```

this returns nothing. Why?

Comment: Because `mike == True` is false.

Comment: how would i properly fix a problem like this?

Comment: @G.Anderson No, it doesn't work like that, either.

Comment: @G.Anderson there's a given operator precedence. Nothing to do with *directions*

Comment: @yatu They have the same precedence, though.

Comment: Its not what you know that gets you, its what you think you know that ain't so.

Comment: Yes, in general terms I mean @heap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a result of [operator chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) which works for the comparison operators `in, not in, is, is not, <, <=, >, >=, !=, ==`. So

```
'error' in mike == True
```

is actually evaluated as:

```
'error' in mike and mike == True
```

the latter of which is false. Operator chaining is more useful for things like `0 < x < 5`.

You want probably just

```
'error' in mike
```

Answer (score 2):

You can force evaluation in the order you want with parentheses:

```
if ("error" in mike) ==True:
    print(True)
```

or, more pythonically:

```
if "error" in mike:
    print(True)
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question ("Why?"), though.

Comment: @HeapOverflow that's fair, I created this answer to give a solution as a placeholder, but every time I try to write up a "why" explanation I realize I'm farther from the mark. Research rabbit hole to get the right words now.